# convert rows to columns using date column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have a table containing four rows: id(primary key, auto increment), value, type and time.

```
id   value  type    time
1    1.2     1    2017-10-26 16:16:49.350 
2    12.4    2    2017-10-26 16:16:49.350 
3    0.6     3    2017-10-26 16:16:49.350 
4    1.1     4    2017-10-26 16:16:49.350 
5    1.8     1    2017-10-25 14:12:24.650 
6    3.2     2    2017-10-25 14:12:24.650 
7    0.2     3    2017-10-25 14:12:24.650 
8    1.2     4    2017-10-25 14:12:24.650
```

Is it possible to convert these rows to columns based on type and time(either by query or stored procedure)? something like this:

```
(type)1     2        3        4       time
1.2        12.4     0.6      1.1     2017-10-26 16:16:49.350
1.8        3.2      0.2      1.2     2017-10-25 14:12:24.650
```

PS: Each four types share the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [id] SMALLINT
   ,[value] DECIMAL(9,1)
   ,[type] TINYINT
   ,[time] DATETIME2
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([id], [value], [type], [time])
VALUES (1, 1.2,  1, '2017-10-26 16:16:49.350')
      ,(2, 12.4, 2, '2017-10-26 16:16:49.350')
      ,(3, 0.6,  3, '2017-10-26 16:16:49.350')
      ,(4, 1.1,  4, '2017-10-26 16:16:49.350')
      ,(5, 1.8,  1, '2017-10-25 14:12:24.650')
      ,(6, 3.2,  2, '2017-10-25 14:12:24.650')
      ,(7, 0.2,  3, '2017-10-25 14:12:24.650')
      ,(8, 1.2,  4, '2017-10-25 14:12:24.650');

SELECT [1], [2], [3], [4], [time]
FROM
(
    SELECT [value], [type], [time]
    FROM @DataSource
) DS
PIVOT
(
    MAX([value]) FOR [type] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) PVT
ORDER BY [time] DESC;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option using conditional aggregation or cross tab.

```
select Type1 = max(case when type = 1 then value)
    Type2 = max(case when type = 2 then value)
    Type3 = max(case when type = 3 then value)
    Type4 = max(case when type = 4 then value)
    , time
from YourTable
group by time
```

Comment: I personally prefer this method than the pivot method. It's more legible and takes few lines to write.

Comment: It is also slightly faster than pivot in all the tests I have done and seen.

Comment: if there is an index on `value`, it can speed things up to add a `WHERE value in (1, 2, 3, 4)`.

Comment: @cmo for that index it would need to be on type. But that also implies they only want rows where those values exist which is not clear from the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PIVOT:

```
SELECT
    [1] type1
    , [2] type2
    , [3] type3
    , [4] type4
    , time
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            value
            , type
            , time
        FROM table
    ) T
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM (value)
        FOR type IN
            (
                [1], [2], [3], [4]
            )
    ) P
```